# Stamp a template with Polymer Templatizer

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0

i want to add the content of a template if required and remove it when it's not required. My code is based on the dom-if implementation of polymer

This is the code to add the content of the template

```
if (!this.ctor) {
  this.templatize(this);
}  
if (parentNode) {
  const parent = Polymer.dom(parentNode);
  if (!this._instance) {
    this._instance = this.stamp();
    const targetNode = parent.firstElementChild;
    const newNode = this._instance.root;
    parent.insertBefore(newNode, targetNode);
  } else {
    const children = this._instance._children;
    if (children && children.length) {
      const lastChild = Polymer.dom(this).previousSibling;
      if (lastChild !== children[children.length - 1]) {
        for (let i = 0, node; i < children.length && (node = children[i]); i++) {
          parent.insertBefore(node, this);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and this is the code to remove the content of the template:

```
if (this._instance) {
  const children = this._instance._children;
  if (children && children.length) {
    const parent = Polymer.dom(Polymer.dom(children[0]).parentNode);
    for (let i = 0, n; i < children.length && (n = children[i]); i++) {
      parent.removeChild(n);
    }
  }
  if(this.restamp) {
    this._instance = null;
  }
}
```

So if i set the restamp attribute to true everything works fine. But if i set it to false some content is not shown.

The content of a dom-repeate template will not be inserted in the code above

```
parent.insertBefore(node, this);
```

Because node contains only #document-fragments but not the content that is inserted by dom-repeat.

I tried to reach the correct content but i failed. Is there a possiblity to insert the correct content, even if it contains dom-repeat, dom-if etc.?

Thank you